# JavaScript: array values are automatically getting deleted

Tags: javascript, html, css, undefined, typeerror

I am making an image slider/ carousel. If you drag it, the images will get momentum and will keep on moving for sometime. There are few issues, one of them is getting the following error frequently: "glide.js:104 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined". JavaScript here is supposed to access a value that is inside an array, but since the array is empty, i'm getting this error. However, the array shouldn't be empty, as the code that empties the array, comes later. [Project](https://yogeshsportfolio.com/slider/)

```js
var projectContainer = document.querySelector(".project-container")
var projects = document.querySelectorAll(".project")

// exProject is declared so that every project has same transalte to refer to instead of referring to their individual transalations
var exProject = projects[0]
var style = window.getComputedStyle(exProject)
exProject.currentTranslationX = (new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform)).m41

// after dragging, do not add force if mouse has not been moved for pauseTime milliseconds
pauseTime = 40
lastMousePositions = []

//this will set margin to 80, i thought this is better than hardcoding
elementAOffset = projects[0].offsetLeft;
elementBOffset = projects[1].offsetLeft;
elementAWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(projects[0]).width)
margin = (elementBOffset - (elementAOffset + elementAWidth))

//projects will teleport to other side if they hit either of the boundary
LeftSideBoundary = -(elementAWidth)
RightSideBoundary = (elementAWidth * (projects.length)) + (margin * (projects.length))

RightSidePosition = RightSideBoundary - elementAWidth;

//how often to update speed (in milliseconds)
intervalTime = 15

//how much speed is lost at every interTime milliseconds
frictionPerMilliseconds = (20 / 1000);
frictionPerMilliseconds *= intervalTime * 5;

mouseInitialPosition = 0;
mouseIsDown = false
startTime = 0;
speed = 0;
mousemoving = false


projectContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  mouseInitialPosition = e.clientX
  mouseIsDown = true;
  startDate = new Date();
  startTime = startDate.getTime();
  lastMousePositions.push(e.clientX)
  speed = 0
})


projectContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  if (!mouseIsDown) return;
  distanceTravelled = e.clientX - mouseInitialPosition

  if (speed === 0) {
    projects.forEach(project => {
      project.style.transform = 'translateX(' + ((exProject.currentTranslationX) + ((distanceTravelled))) + 'px)';
      shiftPosition(project, distanceTravelled)
    })
  }

  if ((new Date()).getTime() - lastMousePositions[lastMousePositions.length - 1][1] > 50) {
    lastMousePositions = []
  }
  pushToMousePositions(e.clientX)

})


projectContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  dragEnd(e);
})

projectContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", e => {
  dragEnd(e);
})

function dragEnd(e) {
  finalPosition = e.clientX;
  distanceTravelled = finalPosition - mouseInitialPosition
  endDate = new Date();
  endTime = endDate.getTime();

  timeElapsed = (endTime - startTime) / 1000

  mouseIsDown = false;

  tempSpeed = distanceTravelled / timeElapsed
  tempSpeed = (tempSpeed / 1000) * 15

  if (tempSpeed < 0 && speed < 0) {
    if (tempSpeed < speed) {
      speed = tempSpeed
    }
  } else if (tempSpeed > 0 && speed > 0) {
    if (tempSpeed > speed) {
      speed = tempSpeed
    }
  } else {
    speed = tempSpeed
  }

  if (lastMousePositions.length === 0) {
    console.log("error gonna pop up")
  }
  if (endTime - (lastMousePositions[lastMousePositions.length - 1])[1] >= pauseTime) {
    speed = 0
  }
  mouseExit(e)
  intervalFunction = setInterval(move, intervalTime)
}

function mouseExit(e) {
  mouseIsDown = false
  lastMousePositions = []

  var style = window.getComputedStyle(exProject)
  exProject.currentTranslationX = (new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform)).m41

  projects.forEach(project => {
    project.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (exProject.currentTranslationX) + 'px)'
    shiftPosition(project, 0)
  })
}

function move() {
  if (speed === 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalFunction)

  } else if (Math.abs(speed) <= frictionPerMilliseconds) {
    style = window.getComputedStyle(exProject)
    exProject.currentTranslationX = (new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform)).m41

    projects.forEach(project => {
      project.style.transform = 'translateX(' + ((exProject.currentTranslationX) + (speed)) + 'px)'
      shiftPosition(project, 0)
    })
    speed = 0
  } else {
    style = window.getComputedStyle(exProject)
    exProject.currentTranslationX = (new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform)).m41

    projects.forEach(project => {
      project.style.transform = 'translateX(' + ((exProject.currentTranslationX) + (speed)) + 'px)'
      shiftPosition(project, 0)
    })

    speed < 0 ? speed += frictionPerMilliseconds : speed -= frictionPerMilliseconds;

  }
}


function pushToMousePositions(positionToPush) {
  if (lastMousePositions.length < 50) {
    lastMousePositions.push([positionToPush, (new Date()).getTime()])
  } else {
    lastMousePositions.shift();
    lastMousePositions.push([positionToPush, (new Date()).getTime()])
  }
}

function shiftPosition(project, mouseMovement) {

  //projectVisualPosition is relative to the left border of container div
  projectVisualPosition = project.offsetLeft + (exProject.currentTranslationX + mouseMovement)
  tempStyle = window.getComputedStyle(project)

  if (projectVisualPosition < LeftSideBoundary) {
    project.style.left = ((parseInt(tempStyle.left) + RightSidePosition + 350) + 'px')
  }
  if (projectVisualPosition > RightSidePosition) {
    project.style.left = ((parseInt(tempStyle.left)) - (RightSidePosition + elementAWidth)) + 'px'
  }
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0px;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

.project-container {
  font-size: 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(15, 207, 224);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.project {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: red;
  border: black 3px solid;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-container">
  <div class="project">1</div>
  <div class="project">2</div>
  <div class="project">3</div>
  <div class="project">4</div>
  <div class="project">5</div>
  <div class="project">6</div>
  <div class="project">7</div>
  <div class="project">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `(lastMousePositions[lastMousePositions.length - 1])[1]`
The code above suggests that `lastMousePositions` is an array of arrays (a 2D array). Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, inside the child array, there is mouseposition, and the time when the position was inserted

Comment: Check line 44 in the mousedown event listener: `lastMousePositions.push(e.clientX)`
What you push there is not an array. Could that be the issue?

Comment: thanks for pointing out, that could possibly have part in increasing the frequency of the error, unfortunately, i am getting the error after replacing it with `pushToMousePositions(e.clientX)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
projectContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
        dragEnd(e);
});
```

You're calling dragEnd(e) when the cursor leaves projectContainer. That can happen while the `lastMousePositions` array is still empty.

**Option 1**: Don't call `dragEnd(e)` on the `mouseleave` event

**Option 2**: Inside the `dragEnd(e)` function, check that the array is not empty before you try to access its elements:

```
if (lastMousePositions.length !== 0) {
          if (
            endTime - lastMousePositions[lastMousePositions.length - 1][1] >=
            pauseTime
          ) {
            speed = 0;
          }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been working on this since many weeks, yet couldn't figure it out